# meteorjs - client side performance issues when dataload is high

Tags: meteor

I subscribed a collection with 10,000 records inside iron-router waiton hook and iterated all the records inside a `{{#each }}` binding in a template. Sub templates inside each binding are complex as well.Loading time was more than 4 mins as I have observed. page initially became unresponsive. Then became responsive after rendering is completed.

Pagination would be a good solution for such a scenario. But I would like to know what is the exact problem for the delay. Is it minimongo update time, minimongo docs size or template rendering time? Query was executed in the server within 20 mili seconds. So this cannot be due to mongodb query execution time.

I logged the the minimongo collection count in browser console as follows before routing to the path.

```
Deps.autorun(function(){ console.log('***Items count: ', Items.find().count())})
```

I have noticed that minimongo is getting updated one by one and sometimes takes more than one second to add a new item to **minimongo**. Sometimes browser became unresponsive when count is around **8000.**

Comment: a smart thing you can do: batch the rerendering by pausing reactivity on the collection and then reenabling it with `pauseObservers` and `resumeObservers`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Any reference or code to read on pauseObservers and resumeObservers ? Could not find anything in meteor docs.

Comment: The code is here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/df2820ffd92bb39d71ed55d884e149fa52b1a376/packages/minimongo/minimongo.js#L982-L1023

Comment: We need some code to answer. But understand this : work on your data will (almost) never freeze your browser. 10 000 records is nothing. There is a solid 99% chance that your problem comes from your template :) Give us at least the template `{{#each yourObject}}` and the helper to generate `yourObject`

Comment: Found the methods in LocalCollection object. can be accessed as Items._collection.pauseObservers() and Items._collection.resumeObservers(). may be helpful for someone

Comment: Yep. I also think its a template binding issue and may be not using cursors properly. If there is no minimongo issue with higher amount of data and iron-router is not surprising me, now i can focus on template binding issues.I am debugging the code now removing sub templates.

This is the only guide line i got : http://projectricochet.com/blog/meteor-js-performance#.U7OkW9SSw8q


 Hopefully someone should build a javascript IDE :)